# Update MySQL entry through PHP form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am writing a script right now to update a MySQL data entry through a PHP form. I know there are lots of tutorials and also a lot of answers here on Stackoverflow. My problem is that I get a "Updated data successfully" message but the data are not updated inside my database. Maybe someone find the error or can tell me what I did wrong and what I have to change. Here is the needed code:

Form:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION)) // if the session not yet started
   session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) { //if not yet logged in
   header("Location: login.php");// send to login page
   exit;
}

include 'header.php';

$get = "SELECT * FROM user email WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'";
 $result_get = mysqli_query($connect, $get);
 $_SESSION['data'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_get);

?>
    <form method="POST" action="update_profile.php" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Vorname:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="firstname_parent" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data']['firstname_parent']; ?>">
    </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="update" value="update" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">PROFIL VERVOLLSTÄNDIGEN</button>
   </form>
```

update_profile.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();
// Create connection credentials
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'DBNAME';
$db_user = 'DBUSER';
$db_pass = 'DBPASS';

// Create mysqli object
$connect = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

// Error Handler
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    printf ("Connection failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error);
    exit();
}   

// Check if form is submitted
if (isset ($_POST['update'])) {
    $update_firstname_parent = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['firstname_parent'] );
}


$sql = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE `user` SET 
     firstname_parent='".$update_firstname_parent."'  WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'";

if (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 0) //<--
{
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
mysql_close($connect); 

?>
```

EDIT:
I changed the update_profile.php due to some comments here. Now I do not get a "Updated data successfully" message, now I only get a blank page and no data is updated inside the database.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: have you tried `...mysqli_affected_rows($sql) == 1...` ?

Comment: Besides your update query being wrong, it seems that you inverted the success/failure messages.

Comment: @099 thanks for your tip, I tried it but same effect. I get the message "Updated data successfully" but no change inside my database

Comment: in **update_profile.php** you have this  **"UPDATE `user` WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."...** - I can't see **session_start();** at the top of the page ! perhaps that's the problem ?

Comment: You need to learn [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) query!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update query is wrong. Change it

```
$sql = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE `user` WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."' (`firstname_parent`) 
        VALUES ('$update_firstname_parent')");
```

to

```
$sql = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE `user` SET 
     firstname_parent='".$update_firstname_parent."'  WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'");
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I tried this query. Now I only get a blank page. No "Updated data successfully" message or any error message. Also nothing has changed inside the database.

Comment: @ChristophC., Sorry, there was a syntax error. Try again

Comment: That´s it! Awesome!! Thank you very much! Just one thing I do not understand. Right now my form has just one input! If my form gets about 20 inputs I have to declare every like you did? So for example: "UPDATE `user` SET firstname_parent='".$update_firstname_parent."', lastname_parent = '".$update_lastname_parent."', street_parent = '".$update_street_parent."' and so on? Am I right?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

   UPDATE table_name
   SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
   WHERE some_column=some_value

Comment: don't forget to escape strings to avoid injections and check for empty strings

Comment: and better if you use PHP PDO http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your `if` statement incorrect? You are checking to see if something is changed and then outputting the error rather than the otherway around?

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 1)
{
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
```

to

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 0) //<--
{
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your QUERY is wrong.

> USE 
>   `"UPDATE ''user SET firstname_parent='".$update_firstname_parent."' WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'";`

Answer (score 0):

There was syntax error in your `UPDATE` and a missing `session_start();` in the `update.php` file. This should work just fine.

> update.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// Create connection credentials
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'DBNAME';
$db_user = 'DBUSER';
$db_pass = 'DBPASS';

// Create mysqli object
$connect = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

// Error Handler
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    printf ("Connection failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error);
    exit();
}   

// Check if form is submitted
if (isset ($_POST['update'])) {
    $update_firstname_parent = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['firstname_parent'] );
}


$sql = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE `user` SET 
     firstname_parent='".$update_firstname_parent."'  WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'");

if (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 1)
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
mysql_close($connect); 

?>


<?php 
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION)) // if the session not yet started
   session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) { //if not yet logged in
   header("Location: login.php");// send to login page
   exit;
}

include ('header.php');

$get = "SELECT * FROM user email WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'";
 $result_get = mysqli_query($connect, $get);
 $_SESSION['data'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_get);

?>
    <form method="POST" action="update_profile.php" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Vorname:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="firstname_parent" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data']['firstname_parent']; ?>">
    </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="update" value="update" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">PROFIL VERVOLLSTÄNDIGEN</button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know if the data is correct try to echo

```
echo($connect, "UPDATE `user` SET 
     firstname_parent='".$update_firstname_parent."'  WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'";
```

if the data shows then your code is correct but here's mine:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("UPDATE user SET firstname_parent='".$update_firstname_parent."'  WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'");
```